# Is jsonToRepJson broken?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm just starting doing some Yesod + Haskell stuff.
Is jsonToRepJson broken or something?

I made this code below but I always get an error in jsonToRepJson part.
It seems it doesn't get the expected type?

Any help would be great! Thanks :3

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Yesod
import Data.Text

data APP = APP

instance Yesod APP

mkYesod "APP" [parseRoutes|
    / TestR GET
|]

getTestR :: Handler RepJson
getTestR = jsonToRepJson $ object ["test".= ("test"::Text)]
main::IO()
main = warpDebug 3001 APP
```

this is what I get when I use runhaskell

```
api.hs:18:12:
    Couldn't match expected type `RepJson' with actual type `Value'
    Expected type: Handler RepJson
      Actual type: HandlerT APP IO Value
    In the expression:
      jsonToRepJson $ object ["test" .= ("test" :: Text)]
    In an equation for `getTestR':
        getTestR = jsonToRepJson $ object ["test" .= ("test" :: Text)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is, I used the `TypeContent` handler.
If I understood correctly what I've read, `repSelect` allows us to easily handle what type of data representation the client asks for.

It reads the request header and checks if it asks for JSON, then it will spit out JSON data, if it needs HTML it will then give the HTML page. Providing that you yourself had added the specific data needed using `providRep`.

Here's my code.

```
mkYesod "APP" [parseRoutes|
        / TestR GET
|]

getTestR::Handler TypedContent
getTestR = do
        selectRep $ do
                provideRep $ jsonToRepJson $ object $ (["test" .= ("test"::Text)])
main::IO()
main = warpDebug 3001 APP
```

Comment: Your 'do's are redundant here, as is the last application operator ($) and you shouldn't be using jsonToRepJson anymore, since it's deprecated ;-)

Answer (score 6):

You must convert your value `toJSON`.

Eg.:

```
jsonToRepJson $ object [("result", toJSON resultValue)]
```

:)

You can read about that change in [Yesod 1.2](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2013/03/yesod-1-2-cleaner-internals)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that one but it didn't work for me. I did read the blog post and it helped me a lot. I'll post my answer. :)